# How to get custom post type label and singular label from its slug?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

Let's say I have a Custom Post Type with the slug `books`. The label is `Readings` and the singular label is `Reading`.

I want to display the Custom Post Type label in one of the custom post type's post. How can I achieve that?

If I want to display a page title from its slug, I can use

```
echo get_the_title(get_page_by_path('other-page-slug'));
```

But I haven't found a clue to do this with custom post type.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `get_post_type_object`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object#Examples

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`get_post_type_object()` will return, as the name suggests, an object that contains the post type information.

You may want to `var_dump()` it to inspect it contents. You'll see that it includes (among other stuff) another object, `labels` that contains all the registered labels for the specific post type.

```
$pt = get_post_type_object( 'books' );

// These two usually contain the post type name in plural. 
// They may differ though.
echo $pt->label;
echo $pt->labels->name;

// This one holds the post type name in singular.
echo $pt->labels->singular_name;
```