# Get name CPT with slug taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

how can I get the name of the CPT having the slug of a Taxonomy?
example:

```
$name_cpt = get_post_type_object( $slug_taxonomy );
```

but this returns `null`.

Does anyone know how to obtain it by means of the slug of the taxonomy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get custom post type label and singular label from its slug?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270999/how-to-get-custom-post-type-label-and-singular-label-from-its-slug)

Comment: No @Akshat, there is the name based on the Slug of the CPT itself, my question is different.

Comment: Hmm... But you know that taxonomy can be assigned to many post types? How exactly should it work?

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż yes!, I know the list of taxonomies, but I need the name of CPT that belongs to each Taxonomy in the list

Comment: OK, so if the taxonomy is assigned to 3 CPTs, you want to get names for all 3 of them?